# jQuery: Hover when browser doesn't have focus

Tags: jquery, browser, drag-and-drop, focus

I am creating a feature similar to Gmail's drag and drop files to upload and have hit a stopping point. I have an alert that works fine on hover over an input when the browser has focus... but when you drag files from your computer the browser loses focus. Gmail can successfully still hover when it does't have focus... how can I replicate this?

I am currently using jQuery like so:

```
$("#upload_media_input").hover(function(){ 
    $("#upload_media_dropzone").fadeIn();
}, function() { 
    $("#upload_media_dropzone").fadeOut(); 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out: http://blog.justswell.org/drag-and-drop-files-from-your-desktop-to-your-browser-using-javascript/

Comment: Thanks, but that is an entire library, I am just looking for the javascript function/code invoked when you drag from the OS to the browser... not a whole proprietary plugin, unless it's jQuery based (which I'm already using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as easy as using `dragover`, `dragexit`, `dragleave` and `drop` on the body:

```
$("body").live("dragover", function(event){ $("#upload_media_dropzone").stop(true, true).fadeTo(200, 1); });
$("body").live("dragexit dragleave drop", function(event){ $("#upload_media_dropzone").fadeTo(200, 0); });
```